# Ruby TDD: how to test against internet connectivity

Tags: ruby, tdd

I'm trying to do some TDD with ruby. I have a class called Browser and it has a method called is_internet_accessible?

I want to write a spec test for this method, to make sure it returns true when google.com is accessible/pingable and false when its not.

How to go about doing this?

My code so far is this:

```
require './browser.rb'

describe Browser do
  before do
    @browser = Browser.new
  end

  describe "#is_internet_accessible?" do
    context "internet down" do
      it "returns false" do
        expect(@browser.is_internet_accessible?).to be(false)       
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You stub the action like Browser.stubs(:"is_internet_accessible?").any_instance.returns(false)

Comment: What is your question? How to implement `is_internet_accessible?` or how to make `is_internet_accessible?` to return false?